# Keep changing active bootstrap on every button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using bootstrap tabs. There are 6 tabs and the 1st tab is active on page load.

```
<ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav-link active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">People</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Current Performance</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Tools</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4">Collaboration Enablers</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu5">Infrastructure</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu6">Practices</a></li>
            </ul>
```

[image]
Now i have a grid-view for with some labels, radio buttons and Next and previous buttons.
So i want the active tab to change every time i click next button. How to do that?
Initially PEOPLE tab is active. On next click CURRENT PERFORMANCE should be active.

Comment: you need to write javascript base on the bootstrap js library

Comment: How? Can you please provide some code possible